# jQuery: get clicked button values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the values of a jQuery button when a form is submitted.  The form and jQuery i'm using is below, but it's not working.

I need to get the value of *data-url*.

**jQuery code**

```
$("#addAgency").submit(function(event) {    
    var val = $("button[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('data-url');
    alert(val);
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form id="addAgency">
    <button type="submit" data-url="test.php">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to place the listener on the button itself, rather than the form.

Comment: You are setting a clicked attribute?

Comment: Check my answer, should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#addAgency").submit(function(event) {    
    var val = $(this).find("button[type=submit]").data('url');
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: this would check for all buttons. in case there would be more on the page

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the `[clicked=true]` and I don't think that is right. The following will find the button from the children of the submitted form.

```
$("#addAgency").submit(function(event) {    
    var val = $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('data-url');
    alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#addAgency").submit(function(event) { 
    alert($(event.target).find('button').data('url'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3y5x6ej/2/